# Change values of a numpy array based on certain condition

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have a 1D numpy array (`A`) containing  5 elements:

```
A = np.array([ -4.0,  5.0,  -3.5,  5.4,  -5.9])
```

I need to add 5 to all the elements of `A` that are lesser than zero. What is the numpy way to do this without for-looping ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done using mask:

```
A[A < 0] += 5
```

The way it works is - the expression `A < 0` returns a boolean array. Each cell corresponds to the predicate applied on the matching cell. In the current example:

```
A < 0  # [ True False  True False  True]
```

And then, the action is applied only on the cells that match the predicate. So in this example, it works only on the `True` cells.

Answer (score 0):

I found another answer:

```
A = np.where(A<0, A+5, A)
```